# javax media player-wont play

Tags: java, try-catch, swingx

Trying to embed a .mp4 video in a JPanel. JPanel will load and execute but video does not. The try{} throws an error but not sure why the try{} is throwing the error. Copied this code from another source but it will not compile.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;    
import java.awt.Component;    
import java.io.File;    
import java.net.MalformedURLException;    
import java.net.URL;    
import javax.media.Manager;    
import javax.media.MediaLocator;    
import javax.media.Player;    
import javax.swing.JFrame;    
import javax.swing.JPanel;    
public class Main extends JPanel 
{    

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

        URL mediaUrl=null;    
        File file = new File("Mortal Combat Video.mp4");     
        System.out.println(file);
        try 
        {    
            mediaUrl = file.toURL(); 
        } 
        catch (MalformedURLException ex) 
        {
            System.out.println(ex);    
        }
    
        JFrame mediaTest = new JFrame( "Movie Player" );    
        mediaTest.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );    
        MediaPlayer mediaPanel = new MediaPlayer( mediaUrl );
        System.out.println(mediaPanel);
        mediaTest.add( mediaPanel );
        
        mediaTest.setSize( 800, 700 ); // set the size of the player    
        mediaTest.setLocationRelativeTo(null);    
        mediaTest.setVisible( true );
    }    
}
```

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;    
import java.awt.Component;    
import java.io.File;    
import java.net.MalformedURLException;    
import java.net.URL;    
import javax.media.Manager;    
import javax.media.MediaLocator;    
import javax.media.Player;    
import javax.swing.JFrame;    
import javax.swing.JPanel;    
public class MediaPlayer extends JPanel {    
public MediaPlayer(URL mediauUrl) {

setLayout(new BorderLayout());    

    Player mediaPlayer = null;
    Component video = null;
    
    Component control = null;
try 
    {

        mediaPlayer=Manager.createRealizedPlayer(new MediaLocator(mediauUrl));          
        video=mediaPlayer.getVisualComponent(); 
        control=mediaPlayer.getControlPanelComponent();
        System.out.println("here3");
        if (video == null)
            System.out.println("video");
        else
        {
            System.out.println("video2");
            add(video, BorderLayout.CENTER); // place the video component in the panel    
        }
        
        add(control, BorderLayout.SOUTH); // place the control in panel    
        mediaPlayer.start();    
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {    
        System.out.println("error");
    }    
}
}
```

### The catch{} prints "error" but not sure why the try{} code will not compile. Any advice is appreciated.

Its running now, video plays, controls work but the video itself is not visible (audio plays).
Here's screenshot:
[image]

Comment: What gets printed when you add `System.out.println(e.getStackTrace());` to the catch that is throwing the error?

Comment: Also, some advice: Don't encapsulate your entire code in a try catch. Rather use smaller try catch blocks for exception-throwing functions. That way, you know where your errors are

Comment: I added screenshots of error output. Does the media player in javax support .mp4 file type? according to docs I believe it does.

Comment: It runs now. Changed file type to .avi. Video is playing, audio works, controls work but the video itself is not displaying? Posted screenshot above.